# Want to separate a string by spaces, but not escaped spaces

Tags: string, split, d

I would like to write some D code that would take a string, and split it by `" "`, but *not* `"\ "`. I normally use `std.array.split` for splitting, but it obviously can't handle this. What would be the best way to do what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions (+ lookbehind) is powerful enough for that:

```
import std.regex;
void main()
{
    auto parts = split(r"foo bar\ bar baz", regex(r"(?<!\\) "));
    assert(parts == ["foo", r"bar\ bar", "baz"]);
}
```

http://dlang.org/phobos/std_regex.html

Comment: I tried that, but then dmd complains that ``std.array.split`` doesn't understand the arguments. Specifically, that set of argument calls doesn't seem to fit its template.

Comment: You should be using `std.regex.split` not `std.array.split`.